# Deep linking for Facebook shareLinkContent

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working with deep link in iOS. I am going to share a link in Facebook using `FBSDKShareLinkContent. I have created deep linking URL in Facebook like `https://fb.me/****************`.

I have already done AppInviteContent and it works good like this:

```
 

let content : FBSDKAppInviteContent = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
content.appLinkURL = NSURL(string: "https://fb.me/****************")!
content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = NSURL(string: "http://***.***.***.***/shareImage.png" as String)!
FBSDKAppInviteDialog.showWithContent(content, delegate: self)
```

Now, I am sharing link in Facebook like this:

```
let shareLinkContent : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
shareLinkContent.contentURL = NSURL(string: "https://example.com/a2d69835ae")!
shareLinkContent.contentTitle = "App_Name"
shareLinkContent.contentDescription = "Description"

let dialog : FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
dialog.fromViewController = self
dialog.delegate = self
dialog.shareContent = shareLinkContent
dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.Web
dialog.show()
```

How to set deep link URL (e.g. `https://fb.me/****************`) in this `shareLinkContent`.

Comment: You want show the Facebook ShareDialog inside your application ?

Comment: @AbilashBNair - Yes Nair.

Comment: What is your FBSDK pod versions?

Comment: @AbilashBNair - FBSDK pod version is 4.12.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very apt idea is to use Branch framework for the deep linking feature. You can get to know how to use this framework from here https://branch.io/

It can be used to share your app contents to any of the social networking sites. it has the feature on universal linking and deep linking.

Comment: Am checking this. What i found is app is installed in mobile. But it goes to iTunes store and ask to open it from there. In this way, I can't open some specific pages.

Comment: It is the default behavior of the branch and you can't go to the specific page of the application. To meet your expectation you have to use the facebook SDK, there you should specify the URL of the specific page. Branch won't support the requirement you asking for, apart from FB it works for all the other social networking sites.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For Facebook only it will goes to iTunes store. So i did fb deep link for facebook and Branch for other social network.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this below code, this have been modified in latest pod version.

```
let dialog : FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
dialog.fromViewController = self
dialog.delegate = self
dialog.shareContent = shareLinkContent
dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.Web
dialog.show()
```

Add this code will show Facebook Share dialog:

```
 FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: shareLinkContent, delegate: self)
```

This will fix your FBSDK share issue.

For APP invite try some thing like this:

```
{
    let content : FBSDKAppInviteContent = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
        content.appLinkURL = NSURL(string: "https://fb.me/****************")!
        content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = NSURL(string: "http://***.***.***.***/shareImage.png" as String)!
        FBSDKAppInviteDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: self)
}
```

Comment: Its working, But Content Title and Content Description are not displaying.

Comment: Facebook stops allowing other content apart from Link inside FBSDKShareLinkContent. For sharing title, description, link you need to use Facebook graph API, but you need "public_action" enabled during facebook login. More info about graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Comment: And my question is am going to share a link and how to add deep link url in sharedLinkContent

Comment: No Abilash. Please understand my question. For me, App invite was successfully working. My need is, am going to use FBSDKShare to share the link. In Facebook app when i tap the shared image, it will be opening the app if installed otherwise it will navigate to App Store to download that app.

Comment: Check this for deep linking : http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking